# Create database and tables with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a db and table creation script. The db is being created, but the tables are not. When I copy my `CREATE TABLE` sql directly into phpMyAdmin, it inserts successfully. So I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
function createdb() {
        include 'DbConnect.php';
        $qry = "CREATE DATABASE chinesegame2";       
        $sql = $mysqli->query($qry);

        $stats = "CREATE TABLE stats (
                    id_stats    INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    PRIMARY KEY (id_stats),
                    id_user_fk  VARCHAR(30),
                    level       VARCHAR(255),
                    experience  INT(10),
                    item_a      INT(10),
                    item_b      INT(10),
                    item_c      INT(10)
                )";

        if ($mysqli->query($stats)) {echo "Table stats created successfully";}
        else { printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);}

   mysqli_close($mysqli);   

}
```

**Result:** chinesegame2 database is created, but no tables are created. `$mysqli->connect_error` only gives "Connect failed:".

Any thoughts why?

Thanks

Comment: can you confirm the connection details are correct? Once you have created the DB you need to connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp

and here https://www.php.net/mysqli_select_db

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Create table
$sql="CREATE TABLE Persons(FirstName CHAR(30),LastName CHAR(30),Age INT)";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Table persons created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
?>
```

and:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY(PID),
FirstName CHAR(15),
LastName CHAR(15),
Age INT
)";
```

Also, make sure that you are in that database **"HAVE IT SELECTED"**, or you tell what database to create a table in. And that your connection details are correct as well.

Comment: Oops, I was using the same connect function for other parts of my project which was connecting to the wrong db. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> only gives "Connect failed:"

That's the string you defined in your code - not the error message. You are only polling for a connect error when you should be polling the connection for *any* error - i.e. mysqli->error(). If you do this it will tell you you've not SELECTED a database (and you haven't explicitly specified a database in your CREATE TABLE statement).

Try:

```
$qry = "CREATE DATABASE chinesegame2";       
$sql = $mysqli->query($qry);
$mysqli->select_db("chinesegame2");
...
```